# My 7 year old sister is annoying sometimes

Tags: age-appropriate

My sister is annoying sometimes and most of the time its at my tired, or already annoyed moments and it just makes it worse. I am turning 17 in July. How can I ask her to stop, or at least tell her that shes being annoying without hurting her feelings?

Comment: Can you give us more details? How old are you? What is she doing? Is she deliberately winding you up or is she just wanting attention? Can you get away from her? What do your parents say about this?

Comment: She is mostly doing it in the car and she is usually annoyed too.

Comment: It is mostly me trying to help her so she doesnt spill something but she jerks it away from me and screams "NO" and ends up spilling it in the process.

Comment: Despite a good answer from Paul, this question isn't really on topic here. It's closer to being on topic for Interpersonal Relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the first step is to stop annoying her. At 7 she is old enough to start taking some responsibility, and it sounds like she feels that way too.

So when the stakes are low you should let her make her own mistakes. If she spills something over herself in the car, well that is her problem (and maybe your parent's problem if it gets on the seat). It is not your problem unless it goes over you too.